# Confluent Control Center Upload connector Error

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-control-center

I am using windows 10, and using docker container to run the confluent control center.
I am trying to upload one of the pre-built connectors that can be found on the confluent hub : https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/?_ga=2.268912561.1564485000.1614024157-1461284509.1612365443

I am getting the following error: "Invalid connector class. Check the connector configuration file."

[image]

I am trying to upload the connector with the following .properties file

```
name=hdfs-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=test_hdfs
hdfs.url=hdfs://localhost:9000
flush.size=3
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot upload a property file using a class that's not available on that page

HDFS 2 Sink no longer comes with Confluent Platform due to security issues

If you're using Docker, you need to install the connector into the container (manually build your own Connect Docker image, use a volume mount, or using confluent-hub), then you should see it available in the list of connectors on that page.

Comment: could you please send docker-compose.Yml file or some example pleases?

Comment: @ParveenKumar Some old version of `confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.x` branch comes with the HDFS2 Connector